# "A: You are always happy but why are you sad today? B: Because I feel lonely." Does B response properly?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, tense

According to [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/feel_1?q=feel)

> feel (linking verb): to experience a particular feeling or emotion
>
> feel + adj: feel well/sick/happy/sad, etc.
>
> I am feeling lonely today. (so, we can use continuous tense with feel with this meaning)

But if we say "**I feel lonely.**", we say that happens regularly.

See this conversation

> A: You are always happy but why are you sad today?
>
> B: Because I feel lonely.

**Does B response properly?**

I would say B is using tenses incorrectly.

I would say the best response should be "**Because I'm feeling lonely**" because I don't feel lonely other days except today.

**Am I right?**

Comment: I would say, it depends on what B wants to express. While A may only be asking about today, perhaps B just usually hides it and has not hidden it as well as B usually does today. As JavaLatte says, both are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [present simple](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-simple) to talk about

- something that is **true right now**
- something that happens regularly
- something that is always true (a permanent state)
- something that will happen in the future.

We use present continuous to talk about a situation that occurs continuously  for some time before and after now.

The first meaning of present simple is usually only used with non-continuous verbs: ones where you don't use present continuous to describe the current situation. These tend to be verbs where can't see the person doing anything, for example want, like and fear. A small number of verbs are mixed: one meaning may be normal and the other non-continuous. An example is **think**, which is used in present continuous to describe the process or thinking and in present simple to express an opinion.

> I am thinking about quitting my job - *process: present continuous*
>   I think that we are nearly finished - *opinion: simple present*

Feel is very unusual in that

> ...there is no real difference in meaning between "I don't feel well today" and "I am not feeling well today. [www.englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/types.html)

You have made it clear that the loneliness is not a permanent state but a temporary thing, nonetheless feeling lonely isn't instantaneous, so it is quite OK to use present continuous to describe your present emotion. It is also reasonable to use present simple to describe your emotion at **this exact moment**, even though it is neither an instantaneous emotion nor a permanent state.

The response is therefore perfectly OK, and your alternative is also OK.

Comment: They said "*something that is true in the present*" not "*something that is true right now*". I would say they mean "*for a situation that we think is more or less permanent.*" but not "*for a temporary situation*" see this page http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-simple-use.html

Comment: http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-continuous-use.html, the page said "*I work in a school.*" (I think this is a permanent situation.) but 
"*I'm working in a school.*" (I think this is a temporary situation.)

Comment: @Tom: Item 3 in the list covers the permanent situations: item 1 is about the situation right now.  "I am tired" and "I am 18 years old" are true now: neither are permanent situations. And you would never say "I am being tired" or "I am being 18 years old".

Comment: Ok, Java Latte, simple present tense can be used to show something that is happening right now but for "non-continuous verbs" (to be, to own, to have) only (http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html). So, "I am tired" = I am feeling tired

Comment: @Tom: I have updated my answer

Comment: ok, so "feel" is kind of ambiguous. It can be both continuous & non-continuous verb

Comment: @Tom: correct. There are other examples of mixed verbs on that page, and I am pretty sure that the list there is not complete. Non-contiunuous is not something that is written down in dictionaries, so for some verbs it may be a matter of personal opiniion whether it is mixed.

Comment: Ok, JavaLatte, you misunderstood a bit!! I understand well that a mixed verb has many meanings, some meanings can have continuous form & other meanings can only have non-continuous form. But, "**feel: to experience a particular feeling or emotion**" can have both continuous & non-continuous form **within the same meaning (to experience a particular feeling or emotion)**.